# Generate javascript accessors to java beans

Tags: java, javascript, code-generation

I'm looking for java framework which can generate javascript code to access backend beans. For example, I have spring service `TestService`:

```
public interface TestService {
    public static class UserDTO {
        public String username;
        public Date birthday;                
    }

    public List<UserDTO> findAllUsersByUsername(String username);
}
```

And I want to call it from javascript like: `console.print(testService.('test')[0].username);` without writing any controller or ajax/xhr stuff. Just run ant/maven/etc task and include js file into html page.

Is that framework already exists?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dwr (http://directwebremoting.org) is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this but only converting the response to json using [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) lib

Comment: Spring already can "expose" controller methods as json using jackson and `@responsebody` annotation. But you still need to write controller and js code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a jar name is Rhino, You should register js on server side, ScriptEngineManager will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I understood from your problem, you want to generate your controllers automatically using your services. You can make use of [`Spring ROO`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html) for this.

Check the reference documentation of Spring ROO [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/index.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I want to generate javascript code (like remote service in GWT) without any controllers. ROO is too complicated to solve my problem. I'm looking for lightweight solution which can expose my java (spring) services in js.